# Redux - Retrieve data from store and POST it

Tags: javascript, reactjs, post, redux

Newbie at Redux back here again, thanks to the question I posted recently I have been able to use redux-logger to keep track of everything that is updated through the store and knowing that every re-render is being happening at my reducer.

The question is still the same, as now that I can see in my log what is happening and everything is being stored in the store, but how can I retrieve it and post it? I need to post through the API to the backend and do some calculations.

The log of my application https://i.stack.imgur.com/jfIfp.jpg

store.js

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import rootReducer from './RootReducer';

export default function configureStore() {
 return createStore(
  rootReducer,
   applyMiddleware(thunk)
 );
}
```

Full code at Sandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/elated-goldberg-1pogb

Thanks in advance!

Comment: check this example https://github.com/waqas-mumtaz/simple-react-redux-counter-app, I created it and it's very simple and easy to understand. If you need any explanation, let me know

Comment: @waqasMumtaz I am sorry but I believe I asked on how to post the data that is stored in the store, I do not see any code regarding that. Can you please explain?